# Spark Structure Streaming multiple aggregation windows

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I am currently woking on spark structure streaming, version 2.11. Can I do the aggregation using two windows (one group by daily, another group by hourly) in only one structure streaming query?

The result table has the both daily data and hourly data?

```
device_id | day | hour | daily_agg_data | hourly_agg_data
a            05     01     123              5
a            05     02     123              6
b            05     01     456              7
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Structured streaming- Using different Windows for different GroupBy Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305002/spark-structured-streaming-using-different-windows-for-different-groupby-keys)